# Libgdx Box2D change shape of a Bodys Fixture

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, shapes

For a game in `libgdx` with `box2d` i would like to be able to let the `Player`
crouch. Crouching should change its `Fixture` to be a 1*1m hitbox instead of a 0.5*2m hitbox.
One possibility would be to store 2 `Body`s, one for normal and one for crouching. Then if the `Player` wants to crouch i could remove the first `Body` from the `World` and add the second `Body`, but this way seems to complex for such an easy task.
Is there an easier possibility to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, one way to solve this would be to have both bodies present.

Specifically, **you can set [Filters](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture.html#setFilterData%28com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Filter%29) on the corresponding Fixtures**. You will then be able  to use alternate the [filters](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Filter.html) to "exempt"/"include" the corresponding from collisions.

Be mindful that, as the JavaDoc for `setFilterData` says:

> Set the contact filtering data. This will not update contacts until
>   the next time step when either parent body is active and awake. This
>   automatically calls Refilter.

For more info, see Section *9.5 Contact Filtering* from the [box2d manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) (it's for the C++ implementation, but should be clear enough for you to get the overall picture), and the aforementioned [Filters JavaDoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Filter.html).

---

EDIT: regarding the comment - for a bonus **you can also actually set the ["unused" body to sleep](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setAwake%28boolean%29)**.

Regarding `Mass`, since you didn't mention it **I assumed you use box2d for collisions only**.

But if it's not the case - well, you will have to check out what works in your simulation and adjust accordingly. For example - a "wider" rectangle (i.e. the "standing" hitbox) might receive a greater rotational momentum when hit in an extremity.

In the "mass" case, you should also consider using a Joint, e.g. a [WeldJoint](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/WeldJoint.html) to "synchronize" your two hitboxes.

Comment: So you mean, i have both `Body`s "active" at once, but one has a collision `Filter`, which filters away all collisions, while the other does not use a filter. And if i switch, i only swith the filter?  
But do 2 `Body`s, with the same `Mass` and `Volume` (in this case only a 2D face) have the same physics, so that the simmulation of Box2D would return the same results?

Comment: @Springrbua : essentially, yes. I've edited the answer to address your other concern.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The "set the body to sleep" will be what i need^^. Then when a player crouches i can set the collision filter as well as the "sleep" flag for the other body and reactivate this+set it to the current position. I won't use rotation for the players so there is no problem for that. I will use Box2D for all kind of physics, cause of the "jump" movement and so on^^